# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.noalumni.model.Users

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm in front of this error since yesterday. I implement a chat app whit Kotlin and I have an issue when I run my code. I got a Firebase DatabaseException:

> Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.noalumni.model.Users

Doesn't anybody know how to fix it? Here is my code.

**NewMessageActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.noalumni.activities

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.example.noalumni.R
import com.example.noalumni.fragments.ChatFragment
import com.example.noalumni.model.Users
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupAdapter
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupieViewHolder
import com.xwray.groupie.Item
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_new_message.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.user_row_new_message.view.*

class NewMessageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    companion object {
        val USER_KEY = "USER_KEY"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_message)
        supportActionBar?.title = "Selectionner un contact"

        fetchUsers()
    }

    private fun fetchUsers() {
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users")
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>()
                p0.children.forEach {
                    Log.d("NewMessage", it.toString())
                    val user : Users = it.getValue(Users::class.java) as Users
                    adapter.add(UserItem(user))
                }
                adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->
                    val userItem = item as UserItem
                    val intent = Intent(view.context, ChatFragment::class.java)
                    //intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, userItem.user.username)
                    intent.putExtra(USER_KEY, userItem.user)
                    startActivity(intent)

                    finish()
                }
                recyclerview_newmessage.adapter = adapter
            }
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
}

class UserItem(val user: Users) : Item<GroupieViewHolder>() {
    override fun bind(viewHolder: GroupieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.itemView.username_textview_newmessage.text = user.username
        Picasso.get().load(user.profileImageUrl).into(viewHolder.itemView.imageview_new_message)
    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.user_row_new_message
    }

}
```

My data class 
Users
**Users.kt**

```
package com.example.noalumni.model
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class Users (val username: String, val email: String, val password: String, val profileImageUrl: String): Parcelable {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "")
}
```

The logcat output

```
2020-06-04 11:09:39.649 5093-5093/com.example.test2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test2, PID: 5093
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.noalumni.model.Users
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:435)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:231)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:203)
        at com.example.noalumni.activities.NewMessageActivity$fetchUsers$1.onDataChange(NewMessageActivity.kt:46)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I just did the edition

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.noalumni.model.Users

Because you are trying to get all children within the `users` node as `User` objects while all objects are actually Strings. To be able to get `User` objects, you need to make a little change in your database structure, so I can look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
        |
        --- uid
             |
             --- email: "badarouyazid98@gmail.com"
             |
             --- password: "azerty"
             |
             --- profileImageUrl: ""
             |
             --- username: "Maria"
```

See there is an extra `uid` node under `users` node? To be able to have such a schema, when you add a User object to the database, use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid)
uidRef.setValue(yourUserObject)
```

Then your actual code will work fine.